# Domain of composition of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $D_f$ and $R_f$ be the domain and range of the function $f$ respectively. Suppose that $D_f \subset A$, and $R_f \subset B $.

Let $D_g$ and $R_g$ be the domain and range of the  $g$ respectively, and $D_g \subset B$, and $R_g \subset C$.

Thus $g \circ f: A \rightarrow C $

Prove that the **domain** of $g \circ f = f^{-1}(D_g) $

---

I can see this in a picture but not sure how to start. Any hint would be nice. But below is my attempted proof:

Proof: Let $D$ be the domain of $g \circ f$, then $D \subset D_f$.
Also, $f(D) \subset R_f \bigcap D_g $.

in fact, $g( R_f \bigcap D_g ) =  $ Range of  $ g \circ f$.

Thus, from here we can see that $f^{-1}( R_f \bigcap D_g$ ) is the domain of $g \circ f$.

Now, there may be points in $D_g$ that do not belong inside $R_f$, for those points, $f^{-1}$ won't do anything. Thus, we can just consider $f^{-1}(D_g)$. So therefore this is the domain of $g \circ f$.

QED

One thing I am a little worry about is the inverse of the function $f$. How do we know for sure that $f$ is one-to one, to guarantee the existence of inverse? where did I go wrong?

Comment: The inverse of a function can be defined even $f$ is not one to one, in which case $f^{-1}(y)=\{x:f(x)=y\}$ is not a value but a set. [My answer in another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3325881/624428) may help.

Comment: We don’t know that f is one-to-one. $f^{-1}(D_g)$ means the pre-image of $D_g$, which means the elements in $D_f$ that map into $D_g$.  It doesn’t mean that $f$ has an inverse.

Comment: I agree with @Feng Shao’s comment, except where he calls that “the inverse of a function”.  I’ve only ever heard it referred to as the pre-image.  It’s unfortunate that it uses the exact same notation, but it’s not the same (although clearly very related). When you see $f^{-1}(7)$ in a calculus class, that usually means that f is an invertible function (one-to-one) and $f^{-1}(7)$ is the unique value $x$ such that $f(x)=7$.  However, in an analysis class, $f^{-1}(7)$ can mean the pre-image of $7$, which is the set of all values that map to 7.  Which it means should be clear from context.

Answer (score 1):

I would prove it by:

$x$ is in the domain of $g \circ f$ if and only if (by the definitions of domain and function composition)

$x \in D_f$ AND $f(x) \in D_g$

If and only if (by the definition of pre-image)

$x \in f^{-1}(D_g)$.